# Search for interval "cross" rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help with a problem in Mysql. I have a table with int intervals like this:

```
|name | start | end  |
---------------------
| aaa | 1531  | 1540 |
| bbb | 1541  | 1550 |
| ccc | 1561  | 1580 |
```

If a user say that needs a interval between 1531 and 1550, I should return true bacause it's available in the table.

Using this query it's not possible:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE start <= 1531 AND end >= 1550
```

I expect the query return to be something different of empty. So the user can use the interval in my app.

Thanks guys!

---

edited: 
I need the return something like this:

```
| aaa | 1531  | 1540 |
| bbb | 1541  | 1550 |
```

or a counter of intervals that match.

other example:

```
|name | start | end  |
----------------------
| aa  | 1     | 100  |
| bb  | 101   | 200  |
| vv  | 201   | 300  |
| dd  | 1501  | 1600 |
| ff  | 1601  | 1700 |
----------------------
```

and I need this:

```
| XXX |    1  |  300 |
| YYY | 1501  | 1700 |
```

So i can search with a simple between

or a counter of intervals

Comment: your where clause is per row but not for cross rows. give some other example rows. and from them explain what exactly you want to fetch. and show how your expected result should look like.

Comment: which version of MySQL are you using? Is it possible the intervals to overlap?

Comment: Edited guys. It's **not** possible the overlapping of values.

Comment: MariaDB 10.3.11

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that the rows never intersect, then you can sum the overlaps:

```
select (sum(1 + least(end, 1550) - greatest(start, 1531)) =
        (1 + 1550 - 1531)
       )
from t
where 1531 <= end and
      1550 >= start;
```